Teensy Based LPC (linear predictive coding) formant shifter, getting no audio
I've been trying to write a realtime formant shifter on the Teensy platform using LPC Linear Predictive Coding. I did use FFT overlap and add approaches but the latency and quality when it comes to a male singers voice just was not acceptable.
I'm currently running into issues with LPC analysis and extracting the formants where the data apears to be consistently wrong.
I currently get no audio and weird output on the log.
I've attached a dump of data and the code.
#include <arm_math.h> // ARM DSP extensions.  https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/index.html
#include <AudioStream_F32.h>

class AudioEffectFormantShifter : public AudioStream_F32 {
public:
    // Constructor
    AudioEffectFormantShifter(void) : AudioStream_F32(1, inputQueueArray_f32) {
        Serial.println("Starting formant shifter");
        generateHanningWindow(window, FRAME_SIZE);
        
        srand(1000);
    }

    void AudioEffectFormantShifter::update(void) {
        audio_block_f32_t* audio_block = AudioStream_F32::receiveWritable_f32();
        if (!audio_block) {
            Serial.println("No audio block received");
            return;
        }
        //applyGain(audio_block, 10.0); -- Testing to see if modifying the audio block and transmitting works (it does!)
        processAudioBlock(audio_block);
        AudioStream_F32::transmit(audio_block);
        AudioStream_F32::release(audio_block);
        //Serial.println("Audio block transmitted");
    }

    void applyGain(audio_block_f32_t* audio_block, float gain) {
        for (int i = 0; i < AUDIO_BLOCK_SAMPLES; i++) {
            audio_block->data[i] *= gain;
        }
    }

    void generateHanningWindow(float32_t* window, int size) {
        const float32_t pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            window[i] = 0.5f * (1.0f - arm_cos_f32(2.0f * pi * i / (size - 1)));
        }
    }

    void processAudioBlock(audio_block_f32_t *audio_block) {
        //Serial.println("Starting processAudioBlock");

        Serial.println("Audio block data:");
        debugPrintBuffer(audio_block->data, BLOCK_SIZE);

        manageBuffer(inputBuffer, audio_block->data, BLOCK_SIZE, FRAME_SIZE, OVERLAP_SIZE);
        Serial.println("After manageBuffer");
        debugPrintBuffer(inputBuffer, FRAME_SIZE);

        applyWindowFunction(inputBuffer, window, FRAME_SIZE);
        Serial.println("After applyWindowFunction");
        debugPrintBuffer(inputBuffer, FRAME_SIZE);

        performLPCAnalysis(inputBuffer, LPC_ORDER, lpcCoeffs, autocorr, reflectionCoeffs);
        Serial.println("After performLPCAnalysis");
        debugPrintLPCResults(lpcCoeffs, autocorr, LPC_ORDER);

        int numFormants = 0;
        extractFormants(lpcCoeffs, LPC_ORDER, formants, numFormants);
        Serial.println("After extractFormants");
        debugPrintFormants(formants, numFormants);

        shiftFormantFrequencies(formants, numFormants, formantShiftFactor);
        Serial.println("After shiftFormantFrequencies");
        debugPrintFormants(formants, numFormants);

        synthesizeModifiedSignal(lpcCoeffs, LPC_ORDER, outputBuffer, FRAME_SIZE);
        Serial.println("After synthesizeModifiedSignal");
        debugPrintBuffer(outputBuffer, FRAME_SIZE);

        applyOverlapAdd(outputBuffer, outputBuffer, FRAME_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, OVERLAP_SIZE);
        Serial.println("After applyOverlapAdd");
        debugPrintBuffer(outputBuffer, FRAME_SIZE);

        for (int i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; i++) {
            audio_block->data[i] = outputBuffer[i + OVERLAP_SIZE];
        }

        delay(10000);
        //Serial.println("Finished processAudioBlock");
    }

    float32_t setFormantShiftFactor(float32_t factor) {
        formantShiftFactor = factor;
        return formantShiftFactor;
    }

    void debugPrintBuffer(const float32_t* buffer, int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Serial.print(buffer[i]);
            Serial.print(", ");
        }
        Serial.println();
    }

    void debugPrintLPCResults(const float32_t* lpcCoeffs, const float32_t* autocorr, int order) {
        Serial.println("LPC Coefficients:");
        for (int i = 0; i <= order; i++) {
            Serial.print(lpcCoeffs[i]);
            Serial.print(", ");
        }
        Serial.println();

        Serial.println("Autocorrelation:");
        for (int i = 0; i <= order; i++) {
            Serial.print(autocorr[i]);
            Serial.print(", ");
        }
        Serial.println();
    }

    void debugPrintFormants(const float32_t* formants, int numFormants) {
        Serial.println("Formants:");
        for (int i = 0; i < numFormants; i++) {
            Serial.print(formants[i]);
            Serial.print(", ");
        }
        Serial.println();
    }

private:
    // Constants
    static const int BLOCK_SIZE = 128;    // Number of samples per audio block
    static const int FRAME_SIZE = 256;    // Frame size for LPC analysis
    static const int OVERLAP_SIZE = FRAME_SIZE / 2;  // 50% overlap (adjusted to match comments)
    static const int LPC_ORDER = 12;      // Order of LPC analysis

    // State-related variables
    audio_block_f32_t *inputQueueArray_f32[1]; // Memory pointer for the input to this module
    float32_t formantShiftFactor = 0.93;  // Formant shift factor, default 1.0 (no shift)

    // Buffers
    float32_t inputBuffer[FRAME_SIZE] = {0};
    float32_t outputBuffer[FRAME_SIZE] = {0};
    float32_t lpcCoeffs[LPC_ORDER + 1] = {0};
    float32_t reflectionCoeffs[LPC_ORDER + 1] = {0};
    float32_t autocorr[LPC_ORDER + 1] = {0};
    float32_t window[FRAME_SIZE];
    float32_t formants[LPC_ORDER / 2];

    // Function prototypes
    void manageBuffer(float32_t* inputBuffer, const float32_t* newBlock, int blockSize, int frameSize, int overlapSize);
    void applyWindowFunction(float32_t* buffer, const float32_t* window, int size);
    void performLPCAnalysis(const float32_t* frame, int order, float32_t* lpcCoeffs, float32_t* autocorr, float32_t* reflectionCoeffs);
    void extractFormants(const float32_t* lpcCoeffs, int order, float32_t* formants, int& numFormants);
    void shiftFormantFrequencies(float32_t* formants, int numFormants, float32_t shiftFactor);
    void synthesizeModifiedSignal(const float32_t* lpcCoeffs, int order, float32_t* outputBuffer, int frameSize);
    void applyOverlapAdd(float32_t* outputBuffer, const float32_t* frame, int frameSize, int blockSize, int overlapSize);
};

// Function implementations
void AudioEffectFormantShifter::manageBuffer(float32_t* inputBuffer, const float32_t* newBlock, int blockSize, int frameSize, int overlapSize) {
    memmove(inputBuffer, inputBuffer + blockSize, (frameSize - blockSize) * sizeof(float32_t));
    memcpy(inputBuffer + (frameSize - blockSize), newBlock, blockSize * sizeof(float32_t));
}

void AudioEffectFormantShifter::applyWindowFunction(float32_t* buffer, const float32_t* window, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        buffer[i] *= window[i];
    }
}

void AudioEffectFormantShifter::performLPCAnalysis(const float32_t* frame, int order, float32_t* lpcCoeffs, float32_t* autocorr, float32_t* reflectionCoeffs) {
    // Step 1: Calculate the autocorrelation coefficients
    for (int k = 0; k <= order; k++) {
        float32_t sum = 0.0f;
        for (int n = 0; n < FRAME_SIZE - k; n++) {
            sum += frame[n] * frame[n + k];
        }
        autocorr[k] = sum;
    }

    // Step 2: Solve the Toeplitz system of equations using Levinson-Durbin recursion
    lpcCoeffs[0] = 1.0f;
    float32_t error = autocorr[0];

    if (error == 0.0f) {
        // If the autocorrelation is zero, return zero coefficients
        for (int i = 0; i <= order; i++) {
            lpcCoeffs[i] = 0.0f;
        }
        return;
    }

    reflectionCoeffs[0] = -autocorr[1] / autocorr[0];
    lpcCoeffs[1] = reflectionCoeffs[0];
    error *= (1.0f - reflectionCoeffs[0] * reflectionCoeffs[0]);

    for (int m = 1; m < order; m++) {
        float32_t sum = 0.0f;
        for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
            sum += lpcCoeffs[j] * autocorr[m + 1 - j];
        }

        reflectionCoeffs[m] = -sum / error;

        for (int j = 1; j <= (m + 1) / 2; j++) {
            float32_t tmp = lpcCoeffs[j] + reflectionCoeffs[m] * lpcCoeffs[m + 1 - j];
            lpcCoeffs[m + 1 - j] += reflectionCoeffs[m] * lpcCoeffs[j];
            lpcCoeffs[j] = tmp;
        }
        lpcCoeffs[m + 1] = reflectionCoeffs[m];
        error *= (1.0f - reflectionCoeffs[m] * reflectionCoeffs[m]);
    }

    // At this point, lpcCoeffs contains the LPC coefficients and
    // reflectionCoeffs contains the reflection coefficients.
}


void AudioEffectFormantShifter::extractFormants(const float32_t* lpcCoeffs, int order, float32_t* formants, int& numFormants) {
    // Bairstow's method for finding roots of a polynomial
    const float32_t tolerance = 1e-6;
    const int maxIterations = 100;

    int n = order;
    int m = n;
    float32_t b[n + 1];
    float32_t c[n + 1];
    float32_t r[n / 2];
    float32_t s[n / 2];
    int numRoots = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        b[i] = lpcCoeffs[i];
        c[i] = lpcCoeffs[i];
    }

    while (m > 2) {
        float32_t dr = 1.0;
        float32_t ds = 1.0;
        float32_t r0 = 0.0;
        float32_t s0 = 0.0;

        int iterations = 0;
        while (iterations < maxIterations) {
            iterations++;

            float32_t d2r = b[m - 2] + r0 * dr;
            float32_t d2s = c[m - 2] + r0 * ds;

            r0 = (b[m - 1] + r0 * d2r - s0 * d2s) / (d2r * d2r + d2s * d2s);
            s0 = (c[m - 1] + r0 * d2s + s0 * d2r) / (d2r * d2r + d2s * d2s);

            dr = r0 * dr - s0 * ds + b[m - 1];
            ds = r0 * ds + s0 * dr + c[m - 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < m - 2; i++) {
                b[i] += r0 * b[i + 2] - s0 * c[i + 2];
                c[i] += r0 * c[i + 2] + s0 * b[i + 2];
            }

            if (fabs(dr) < tolerance && fabs(ds) < tolerance) {
                break;
            }
        }

        r[numRoots] = -r0;
        s[numRoots] = -s0;
        numRoots++;
        m -= 2;
    }

    numFormants = numRoots;
    for (int i = 0; i < numRoots; i++) {
        formants[i] = sqrt(r[i] * r[i] + s[i] * s[i]);
    }

    // Debugging information
    Serial.println("LPC Coefficients:");
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        Serial.print(lpcCoeffs[i]);
        Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("Formants:");
    for (int i = 0; i < numRoots; i++) {
        Serial.print(formants[i]);
        Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println();
}

void AudioEffectFormantShifter::shiftFormantFrequencies(float32_t* formants, int numFormants, float32_t shiftFactor) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numFormants; i++) {
        formants[i] *= shiftFactor;
    }
}

void AudioEffectFormantShifter::synthesizeModifiedSignal(const float32_t* lpcCoeffs, int order, float32_t* outputBuffer, int frameSize) {
    memset(outputBuffer, 0, frameSize * sizeof(float32_t));

    float32_t excitation[FRAME_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < frameSize; i++) {
        excitation[i] = (float32_t)rand() / (float32_t)RAND_MAX - 0.5f;
    }

    for (int n = order; n < frameSize; n++) {
        float32_t sum = excitation[n];
        for (int k = 1; k <= order; k++) {
            sum -= lpcCoeffs[k] * outputBuffer[n - k];
        }
        outputBuffer[n] = sum;
    }
}

void AudioEffectFormantShifter::applyOverlapAdd(float32_t* outputBuffer, const float32_t* frame, int frameSize, int blockSize, int overlapSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
        outputBuffer[i] += frame[i + overlapSize];
    }
    memmove(outputBuffer, outputBuffer + blockSize, overlapSize * sizeof(float32_t));
    memset(outputBuffer + overlapSize, 0, blockSize * sizeof(float32_t));
}


Output Log also produces no audio:
Audio block data:
0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 
After manageBuffer
0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 
After applyWindowFunction
0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 
After performLPCAnalysis
LPC Coefficients:
1.00, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.01, 
Autocorrelation:
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.22, 0.22, 
LPC Coefficients:
1.00 -1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 
Formants:
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 
After extractFormants
Formants:
0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 
After shiftFormantFrequencies
Formants:
0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 
After synthesizeModifiedSignal
0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, -0.17, 0.20, 0.07, 0.56, 0.24, 0.58, 0.79, 1.09, 1.41, 1.89, 1.80, 1.47, 1.48, 1.81, 1.54, 1.43, 1.85, 1.55, 1.25, 1.22, 1.52, 1.14, 1.06, 1.24, 1.28, 1.67, 1.24, 1.27, 1.69, 1.41, 1.01, 0.84, 0.45, 0.46, 0.50, 0.62, 0.61, 0.63, 0.44, 0.50, 0.73, 1.06, 0.96, 0.82, 0.87, 0.91, 0.89, 1.15, 0.93, 1.32, 0.94, 0.91, 0.61, 1.06, 1.51, 1.48, 1.86, 2.29, 2.34, 2.21, 2.40, 2.36, 2.21, 2.00, 2.30, 2.15, 2.25, 2.65, 2.70, 2.80, 3.22, 3.36, 3.22, 2.95, 2.90, 2.92, 3.03, 3.15, 2.92, 2.69, 2.36, 2.53, 2.56, 2.23, 1.74, 1.45, 1.46, 1.86, 2.18, 2.60, 2.55, 2.10, 2.13, 2.15, 2.33, 2.21, 2.42, 2.57, 2.51, 2.76, 3.10, 2.58, 2.57, 2.98, 2.86, 2.36, 2.28, 2.41, 2.69, 3.02, 2.68, 2.99, 3.33, 3.56, 3.33, 2.96, 3.24, 2.94, 2.61, 2.47, 2.36, 2.14, 2.29, 2.71, 3.06, 2.53, 2.33, 2.70, 3.14, 3.01, 2.89, 2.74, 2.40, 2.79, 2.93, 2.57, 2.56, 2.74, 2.67, 3.03, 2.57, 2.65, 2.21, 2.14, 2.19, 1.98, 2.25, 2.11, 1.87, 1.35, 0.98, 1.41, 1.31, 1.09, 1.16, 1.41, 1.16, 1.34, 1.25, 1.66, 2.14, 2.25, 2.18, 1.92, 1.78, 2.02, 2.30, 2.01, 2.39, 2.50, 2.86, 2.69, 3.04, 3.36, 2.94, 2.63, 2.46, 2.44, 2.02, 1.91, 1.91, 1.43, 1.55, 2.00, 1.52, 1.63, 1.90, 1.49, 1.14, 1.56, 1.10, 1.19, 1.60, 1.72, 1.81, 1.55, 1.10, 1.56, 1.24, 1.65, 1.29, 1.65, 1.54, 1.74, 1.52, 1.65, 1.71, 1.87, 2.28, 2.38, 2.41, 2.35, 2.61, 2.18, 2.44, 2.64, 3.10, 3.29, 3.50, 3.47, 3.85, 3.36, 3.49, 3.02, 2.94, 2.78, 2.88, 2.99, 2.67, 2.72, 2.77, 2.68, 2.68, 2.76, 2.37, 2.04, 2.48, 2.32, 2.77, 2.69, 2.97, 3.03, 3.19, 3.39, 
After applyOverlapAdd
3.24, 2.94, 2.61, 2.47, 2.36, 2.14, 2.29, 2.71, 3.06, 2.53, 2.33, 2.70, 3.14, 3.01, 2.89, 2.74, 2.40, 2.79, 2.93, 2.57, 2.56, 2.74, 2.67, 3.03, 2.57, 2.65, 2.21, 2.14, 2.19, 1.98, 2.25, 2.11, 1.87, 1.35, 0.98, 1.41, 1.31, 1.09, 1.16, 1.41, 1.16, 1.34, 1.25, 1.66, 2.14, 2.25, 2.18, 1.92, 1.78, 2.02, 2.30, 2.01, 2.39, 2.50, 2.86, 2.69, 3.04, 3.36, 2.94, 2.63, 2.46, 2.44, 2.02, 1.91, 1.91, 1.43, 1.55, 2.00, 1.52, 1.63, 1.90, 1.49, 1.14, 1.56, 1.10, 1.19, 1.60, 1.72, 1.81, 1.55, 1.10, 1.56, 1.24, 1.65, 1.29, 1.65, 1.54, 1.74, 1.52, 1.65, 1.71, 1.87, 2.28, 2.38, 2.41, 2.35, 2.61, 2.18, 2.44, 2.64, 3.10, 3.29, 3.50, 3.47, 3.85, 3.36, 3.49, 3.02, 2.94, 2.78, 2.88, 2.99, 2.67, 2.72, 2.77, 2.68, 2.68, 2.76, 2.37, 2.04, 2.48, 2.32, 2.77, 2.69, 2.97, 3.03, 3.19, 3.39, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 

I've tried bypassing the processAudioBlock function and applying a gain on the audio_block samples and transmitting them, which works just fine.
I've also (shamefully) asked Copilot to help, which hasn't really solved the issue.
The processAudioBlock function should:

manageBuffer: This function is responsible for managing the input buffer. It shifts the existing data in the buffer and adds new data from the incoming audio block.

applyWindowFunction: This function applies a Hanning window to the input buffer. The Hanning window is a type of tapering window used in signal processing to reduce spectral leakage.

performLPCAnalysis: This function performs Linear Predictive Coding (LPC) analysis on the input buffer. LPC analysis is a method used to represent the spectral envelope of a signal by predicting each sample as a linear combination of the previous samples.

extractFormants: This function extracts formant frequencies from the LPC coefficients. Formants are resonant frequencies in the vocal tract that characterize different speech sounds.

shiftFormantFrequencies: This function adjusts the formant frequencies based on a shift factor. It allows for manipulation of the spectral characteristics of the audio signal, which can change the perceived vowel sound.

synthesizeModifiedSignal: This function synthesizes a modified audio signal using LPC coefficients. It generates an excitation signal and applies LPC synthesis filtering to produce the output signal.

applyOverlapAdd: This function applies overlap-add processing to the output buffer. It adds the current frame of processed audio to the output buffer with overlap, ensuring smooth transitions between consecutive frames.


But I currently get no audio and weird output on the log.

you are not done debugging this. [mre] required. yes, in the worst case, you'll have to completely take your code apart, or start from scratch with smaller steps, testing on specific data that might even be hand-crafted. maybe prototype this on a computer, not on the target. -- did you copy this from a class assignment? the structured writing is unusual. -- it's good that you asked AI for help first. most people should do that, so they realize that other humans still have value.
